# Not able to retrieve data from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I am saving a list of objects in local storage.by below code

```
var employeeArray = [];
 function SaveData() {
        counter = counter + 1;
        employeeArray.push
        ({
            ID : counter,
            FirstName : $('#txtFirstName').val(),
            LastName : $('#txtLastName').val(),
            MobileNo : $('#txtMobileNo').val(),
            Address : $('#txtAddress').val()
        })
        localStorage.setItem("employee", employeeArray);
        BindData();
    }
```

when i am retrieving data from local storage by below code

```
function BindData() {
        var employee = localStorage.getItem("employee");
        for (var key in employee) {
            alert(key);

            var tr = CreateElement('tr', null)
            tr.append(CreateElement('td', employee[key]));
            $('#tblData').append(tr);
        }
    }
```

`key`  gives me only indexes value like 0,1,2.... I am looking for the name of the property to be used like `key.ID` .

How can it be achieved ??

Comment: localStorage only understands strings. You should stringify your struct on set and decode on get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the storage api, the values are stored as string values, so you need to convert the `employeeArray` to a json string before storing

```
localStorage.setItem("employee", JSON.stringify(employeeArray));
```

then while reading, you need to convert the string back to an object like

```
function BindData() {
  var employee = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("employee"));
  employee.forEach(function(emp) {
    var tr = CreateElement('tr', null)
    tr.append(CreateElement('td', emp.FirstName));
    $('#tblData').append(tr);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun I did not knew about string values. Can i use any other loop than .foreach to retrieve the property values

Comment: You can use any for loop, for `$.each()`